# Remove specific characters from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am creating a form to lookup the details of a support request in our call logging system.

Call references are assigned a number like `F0123456` which is what the user would enter, but the record in the database would be `123456`. I have the following code for collecting the data from the form before submitting it with `jQuery` ajax.

How would I strip out the leading `F0` from the string if it exists?

```
$('#submit').click(function () {        
            
var rnum = $('input[name=rnum]');
var uname = $('input[name=uname]');

var url = 'rnum=' + rnum.val() + '&uname=' + uname.val();
```

Comment: If it's always the first two chars, with [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr). Otherwise you need to specify the question better.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Simply replace it with nothing:

```
var string = 'F0123456'; // just an example
string.replace(/^F0+/i, ''); '123456'
```

Comment: Might be a little misleading to include that `+`. Also as this is a "first instance" replace I would have been inclined to have gone for a non-regex replace (but that isn't really important) or a `substr`

Comment: @AlphaPapa I didn’t know you wanted it to be case-insensitive. Answer added and `i` flag added. @musefan, I didn’t know if OP wanted to omit only the first leading zero, or all leading zeroes.

Comment: @MathiasBynens: I think you should comment about the `+`. IF the case number happens to be 000001 it may cause bugs that the OP cant work out. Of course it is all down to the exact implementation of the system

Answer (score 30):

Honestly I think this probably the most concise and least confusing, but maybe that is just me:

```
str = "F0123456";
str.replace("f0", "");
```

Dont even go the regular expression route and simply do a straight replace.

Answer (score 15):

If you wish to remove all occurrences of `F0` from a given string, you can use the [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method.

```js
const str = 'F0123F0456F0'.replaceAll('F0', '');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 9):

Another way to do it:

```
rnum = rnum.split("F0").pop()
```

It splits the string into two: `["", "123456"]`, then selects the last element.

Answer (score 8):

Regexp solution:

```
ref = ref.replace(/^F0/, "");
```

plain solution:

```
if (ref.substr(0, 2) == "F0")
     ref = ref.substr(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

if it is not the first two chars and you wanna remove F0 from the whole string then you gotta use this regex

```js
   let string = 'F0123F0456F0';
   let result = string.replace(/F0/ig, '');
   console.log(result);
```